If nothing existed, would even the fact that nothing exists not exist either?
Suppose absolutely nothing existed. Not just no material objects, but also no space, no time, no God, and even no mathematical entities. In such a case, would even the fact that nothing exists itself not exist either? Also, what have philosophers written about this question?

Do facts exist? You can ask whether Santa Claus exists (he doesn't), or elfs (alas, also not). Or atoms and molecules (yes). Aliens? Perhaps. But facts? Why would you ascribe existence to facts? Santa Claus does not exist. This is a fact. It is true that Santa Claus does not exist. But now you also want to say, since Santa does not exist: "The fact that Santa does not exist exists"?

The question is another pseudo-paradox arising from the clever misuse of language. So is Godel's proof of the inconsistency of formal systems. It's the logical equivalent of asserting T = F, then standing around amazed at the "paradox."

The Eleatic school of pre-Socratic philosophy (Parmenides, Zeno, etc.) were staunch believers that not only is non-being impossible, we can't even speak about it; Essentially, being cannot come from or interact with non-being.
Despite a couple thousand years of discourse around the topic, I think the better question is 'Is nonexistence possible?', or perhaps 'Can I conceive the concept of nonexistence clearly enough to talk about it with accuracy?'
Ultimately, I think that in order for nonexistence to be qualified (i.e. assertion that there's nothing) there needs to be an observer, which defeats the idea. The concept of 'fact', or any other idea really, only exists if something else is there to perceive it.
